# Qt how to hide cross bar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

How can I hide completely this section with red marked.
[image] Any QWidget implementation will work for me I guess!

Comment: A google of "qt how to hide window controls" produced [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6588) page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are controlled by [`Qt::WindowFlags`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum).  Have a look at the [Window Flags example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html) to figure out the flags you want.